# How to validate number of cells in UITableView with XCUITest when loaded asynchronously?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcuitest

I'm writing a UI Test that needs to load data asynchronously and then do some validation on the data as presented in the cell.

In this case if no data loads the tests pass and shouldn't so I need to make sure that I have at least one cell that has loaded based on the remote data.

```
func testTableViewCellDoesNotContainItem() {
  ...setup....

  // Load data 
  app.keyboards.buttons["Search"].tap()
  XCTAssert(app.tables["TableView"].cells.count > 0)

  ...other check...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Was able to achieve the desired effect with the following:

```
func testTableViewCellDoesNotContainItem() {
  ...setup....

  // Prep expectation for async load ensuring that we have at least one cell and the service call worked
  let loaded = NSPredicate(format: "count > 0")
  expectation(for: loaded, evaluatedWith: app.tables["TableView"].cells, handler: nil)

  // Load data 
  app.keyboards.buttons["Search"].tap()
  waitForExpectations(timeout: 5, handler: nil)

  ...other check...
}
```